# Python optimizing shape overlap detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, pygame, list-comprehension

I've been working on a tile based platformer in Python using Pygame. After making the map of tiles bigger, I experienced a big performance slowdown. I used a profiler to find the cause of the slowdown, and it pointed to the list comprehension I use to check which tiles are on the screen.

```
[i for i in sprites
     if (i.rect.x-pos.x)+(WIDTH/2)+i.w>0
     and (i.rect.x-pos.x)+(WIDTH/2) < WIDTH 
     and (i.rect.y-pos.y)+(HEIGHT/2)+i.h>0
     and (i.rect.y-pos.y)+(HEIGHT/2) < HEIGHT]
```

Is there any way to optimize this? Anything that will help it finish its task faster will help.

Comment: As @Nathan's answer demonstrates, this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You asked about speeding up your comprehension, but what you really wanted was a more efficient way to detect shape overlap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the size of the screen a rectangle and use the builtin collision detection:

```
[i for i in sprites if i.rect.colliderect(screen_rect)]
```

It turns out there's an [actual function for this](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) without list comprehension, likely to be faster still:

```
spritecollide(screen, sprites, True, collided = None)
```

Comment: How is this faster?

Comment: @Qwerty in my experience, written functions are always worse than existing functions. Also, there's really no other way to optimize your code because this is literally all the code available.

Comment: so have you tested and proven it faster, or are you just assuming

Comment: @Qwerty Well, you don't have a working example, do you expect me to write a whole game just to check one line of code?

Comment: It seems highly probably that pygame's authors have put a lot of effort into something as basic to gaming as collision detection.

Comment: @Qwerty btw, how many sprites do you have? I made a game to test the code, and both (with well over 1000 sprites) run so fast through this bit of code that I cannot time it...

Comment: The pygame implementation is [written in C](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/master/src/rect.c#L455-L464). Its pretty unlikely that your list comprehension is faster so its hard to see  how it could hurt.

Comment: the `spritecollide` function looks equivalent to your list comprehension with the exception that they avoid an attribute lookup each time by [assigning colliderect to a variable](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/master/lib/sprite.py#L1524-L1525)

Comment: @avigil so you're saying I should remove the first half of the answer?

Comment: I think its still useful as it is. The intent of the code might arguably be more clear using a list comprehension and rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

1. Rewrite the condition as `-i.w < (i.rect.x-pos.x)+(WIDTH/2) < WIDTH and -i.h < (i.rect.y-pos.y)+(HEIGHT/2) < HEIGHT`. It will increase readability at least, and might improve performance.
2. Use a generator expression instead of the list comperension if possible. It definitely will reduce memory usage.
3. In fact, your condition may be rewritten in vector form (dim = 2) and SIMD may be useful here. Explore this opportunity.

Comment: Could you please explain your last one?

Comment: `-i.w < (i.rect.x-pos.x)+(WIDTH/2) < WIDTH and -i.h < (i.rect.y-pos.y)+(HEIGHT/2) < HEIGHT` can be rewritten in 2-vector form `-A < (B - P) + C < C/2` where `A = (i.w, i,h)`, `B = (i.rect.x, i.rect.y)`, `P = (pos.x, pos.y)`, `C = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)`. Some libraries, `numpy` for example, can process such vector operations mush faster by using SIMD processor instructions.

Comment: But you hardly need to apply all of those _general tips_ here. I have never worked with PyGame, so for you it is better to just use the specific answer of @Nathan here, as it turned out that there is a function for your problem